# Convert nginx $query_string in location to a params

Tags: nginx, regex, uri

I want to use the location and convert a URL to GET parameters in my server. I don't care if it is one, two or more params in the URL but it would be something like this, if I go to this URL

https://www.example.com/page/one/two/three/ ....

it should send me to this

https://www.example.com/page/index.php?site=one&id=two&args=three ....

I set up my code to get up to the first parameter in the URL but I cannot break it down further, it will always return everything after `page/` together in one paramemter

```
        location ~ ^/page/(.*)$ {
            try_files $uri /page/index.php?site=$1
        }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to improve the scope of the captures in your regular expression. The capture `(.*)` will absorb anything and is greedy. You could a lazy quantifier in the capture (e.g. `(.*?)`), or a character class which excludes the separating `/` (e.g. `([^/]+)`).

For example, to implement the three cases as separate rules:

```
location ~ ^/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) {
    try_files $uri /page/index.php?site=$1&id=$2&args=$3;
}
location ~ ^/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+) {
    try_files $uri /page/index.php?site=$1&id=$2;
}
location ~ ^/page/([^/]+) {
    try_files $uri /page/index.php?site=$1;
}
```

Regular expressions are evaluated in order until a match is found, so the more specific rule must be placed before a less specific rule. Also, these will all need to be placed after the `location ~ \.php$` block, otherwise your PHP URIs will break.

See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expression syntax.

Comment: thank you so much. That approach was just what I needed.